# PhoneGap device ready doesn't fire the second time I open the app, xcode deployment

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, build

According to the PhoneGap documentation it's best practice to put your initially executed javascript inside a "deviceready" event handler. I'm testing my app by deploying to my iphone from xcode. When I initially run the app on my phone the "deviceready" event fires and everything works fine, but if I close the app and open it back up the UI comes back in the same state I left it in and the "deviceready" event doesn't fire. Does anyone know how this issue is typically dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

The iOS application have different event on it. (ViewWillLoad, ViewDidLoad, ViewWillAppear...). I think that phonegap use the ViewDidLoad, this event it's call just one time, when the app is launched (When you see the splashScreen). After that the application is memorised. That why, I think, the deviceready it's not called (cause it's already loaded). You should changed your event, in order the get an event each time you go on this page.

Hope this help ;)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I don't see any of the events you listed on the PhoneGap API documentation http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html

Comment: see this link, https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW3 I couldn't find the viewdidload event, but the principe is here

Answer (score 0):

It turns out I wasn't actually restarting app, it was still running in the background on my phone. If I actually do turn the app of the "deviceready" event does fire. I one needs to run code when an app running in the back ground is restarted it can be done via the pause and resume events.